# How can I add something to serialized form values using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I can not figure out the syntax for this.

Here's my code:

```
$('select[id^="lookup_"]').change(function() {
    var d = $("#lookupform").serializeArray();

            // This is the problem line
            d.push("field=" + $(this).id);

    hash = { type: "POST", url: "/map/details", data: d };
    $.ajax(hash);
    return false;
});
```

I know that problem line is totally wrong. I basically want to let the server side know from which the submission came from. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do:

```
d.push( { field: this.id } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very, very close. This will work:

```
d.push("field=" + this.id);
```

Or, to be consistent with the other array elements:

```
d.push({field: this.id});
```

Comment: BTW, are you sure you want to be using [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray) and not [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize)?

Comment: I am definitely supposed to be using .serialize() instead, but I wasn't sure how to serialize a single entry, nor what object to use.